# Bootstrap 3.0 grid newbie problems

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to construct a form using Bootstrap Grid but ran into some problems.
The page can be found on [input-page](http://bmrm.harry-arends.nl/)

The first problem is the section width. The form is 5,5,2 = 12 but in the two 5 columns the element doesn't show correctly.

Second how do I get the input fields nearer, vertically, to each-other?

Third how do I get the columns the same vertical size so it doesn't show the main background colour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `input` width from `100%` to `auto` and that will allow for the placeholders to be visible.

`.form-group` needs the `padding-bottom` adjusted so the input fields are closer to each other.

For the background, this is one of the faults of bootstrap. It doesn't allow for equal heights. There are several ways around this and table-cells are the most common. I use a class on the row so I can target specifically that section if I have other rows I don't need it for. Then you need to clear for

```
.row.equal-height {
    display: table;
}

.row.equal-height [class*="col-"] {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #D4BD72;
 }

  @media screen and (max-width:767px){
    .row.equal-height{
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
     }
}
```

I'll see if I can get this in a Bootply for you :) Overrides would need to be taken for the columns inside of the form-group to work.

See working http://www.bootply.com/RSBHrQeOZ6

Comment: "For the background, this is one of the faults of bootstrap" I'd say it's a fault in CSS that CSS doesn't make it easy/possible to create perfect grid systems.

Comment: @cvrebert Zurb has a function to assist with equal heights already built into their framework to compensate. See http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html. Bootstrap doesn't have anything, which is why I say it is a fault.